# Keras Conv2d dim error

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

> Error when checking input: expected conv2d_input to have 4 dimensions,
>   but got array with shape (1000, 32, 32)

Is what i get when i try to add Conv2d as my first layer. Im providing the network with [1000,32,32] array which is a thousand 32x32 piuctures

```
model = keras.Sequential([
keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same',data_format="channels_first", input_shape=(1,32,32)),
keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.tanh),
keras.layers.Dense(128,activation=tf.tanh)
])
```

Whats the problem? How do i set the dimensions for my input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model expects an explicit dimension for the channels in the input, even if you only have one channel. If your images are `np arrays`, you can add a dimension as follows:

```
import numpy as np

image = np.random.rand(1000,32,32)
image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=1)
image.shape

output: (1000, 1, 32, 32)
```